# MongoDB TTL unexpected expire time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to create a record with a schema that will delete after time-set, but it will always delete after 1-2 min no matter how long I set.

I tried follow the official mongoDb TTL document and other articles, but it doesn't work as expected

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const moment = require('moment');


const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    token:{
        type: String,
    },
    emailVery:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    createdAt:{ 
        type: Date, 
        required: true,
        default: Date.now   
    }
});

UserSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds : 3600 });


const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

It also have a error:
node:20228) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
while I never use collection.ensureIndex anywhere on my code.

Comment: Which MongoDB version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your syntax, it seems you are using mongoose `3.X` version and MongoDB is higher than `3.0`.

You should update your mongoose version and then use indexes feature.

**Mongoose:**

Below is the syntax from mongoose 5.X version:

```
var s = new Schema({ date: { type: Date, index: { unique: true, expires: '1d' }})
s.path('my.date').index({ expires: 60 });
```

> `.index` will call `createIndex` of mongoDB.

---

**MongoDB**

> Deprecated since version 3.0.0: **db.collection.ensureIndex()** is now an alias for **db.collection.createIndex()**.

```
UserSchema.createIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds : 3600 });
```

And probably, `expireAfterSeconds` should work correctly.

Hope this help!